# How to convert current source to voltage source when to current sources are in parallel?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source, voltage-source

I've been given the following diagram with two current sources:
[image]

I have to calculate the current shown by the ampermeter (A) which is quite easy once I'm done with the conversion.
The theory says the following (current source to voltage source):

[image]

This is my attempt but I' think I've done something wrong (made in Paint)

[image]

Comment: So you have two pairs of current source + parallel resistor. Just convert them one by one.

Comment: Does this mean my diagram (last one) is totally wrong?

Comment: @kenlir, where are the two current sources that are in parallel? I see them in parallel with different resistors not with each other. Why do you want to convert the current source to the voltage source, when the circuit seems easy as it is.? Were you told to solve the current going through the Ampmeter in a certain/specific way? Your last diagram is not totally wrong. Please let me know when you are back online so that you and I can come up with a solution step by step.

Comment: @dsmith The problem is that I don't know how to solve it with current sources only with voltage sources I feel more comfortable with them..

Comment: Add the current sources (they add in parallel, just like voltage sources do in series). That should make the circuit a lot simpler.

Comment: @kenlir, I understand but were you told to solve it in a specific way or were you told to just get the answer?

Comment: @dsmith just the answer...

Comment: okay. @kenlir I see. Are we assuming the ampmeter has no load/resistance? As in it is just a straight wire?

Comment: Yes. that's correct.The results given are in between 1-5 A

Comment: okay. @kenlir, so yes you are right. They are in parallel. What have you been taught? Mesh/Nodal Analysis? Voltage Divider? Like what have you learnt so that I can adjust my answer. There are many ways to solve it. Have u been taught Thevenin & Norton Equivalent?

Comment: @kenlir, from what I see the two easist ways in solving this circuits is either by:

Comment: @dsmith  Just not Norton and Thevenin the easies possible way please..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45438/discussion-between-dsmith-and-kenlir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By what i can see you diagram is wrong.
To convert the two current sources you convert the sources considering the parallel resistors as the figure below.

[image]

To convert the current source to a voltage source you first substitute the pair (current source)-(resistor in parallel) by a series association of a voltage source and a resistor with the same value as the resistor in parallel.
The value of the voltage source is given by the formula V=R*I.
Pay attention to the direction ofthe voltage source as it needs to have the same direction as the current source.

Applying the transformation leads to the following circuit.

[image]

Comment: Tnx for that I forgot the source on the right hand side and obviously the left hand side stays in parallel cut of by one line. I got my result now easily (If I didn't do anything wrong than it should be 4)

Comment: Actually the current in the ampermeter is 0.5 Amps.

Comment: O yes you are right 0.5 is in the anser I've miscalculated something..